# how do I code google advanced search in html?

Tags: html

I'm trying to use the name input attribute to make get requests so I can make a copy of google advanced search.

```
<form method= "get" action="https://www.google.com/search?as_q">
        <input type="text" name="as_q">
</form>
```

How do I change the name attribute so that I can make the other search fields like "all these words:", "any of these words:", etc...?

Comment: You can not do this with HTML alone. You will need Javascript to hit their [search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search) Note that only the simple search is free. If you want to make advanced queries, the current pricing is 5$ per 1000 queries, with a maximum of 10,000 queries per day

Answer (score 0):

You can try [entering different values for each search parameter on the advanced search page](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) and see how the parameter names come out in the URL. Each `input` must have a `name` corresponding to that parameter.

Also, your `action` doesn't need the `as_q` part (the parameters will be provided by the form input).

Edit: This is assuming you're happy with redirecting to the actual Google results page upon form submission. Actually showing Google results on your own page is far beyond what pure HTML is capable of, as @sinanspd mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In your action="" attribute make sure you have the normal google search url (https://www.google.com/search), in your name="" make sure have (as_q, as_epq, as_epq, as_eq) as the attribute's value.